# How to change showTotal postiton in antd pagination component

Tags: reactjs, pagination, components, antd

`showTotal` is currently aligned to the left of the pagination ( list of numbers ) always.

How to change its position.

Refer to the image below to understand the expected behavior

[image]

Documentation for Reference: https://ant.design/components/pagination/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altough it is a `li` inside a `ul`, you can trick it somehow using absolute position

```
.ant-pagination-total-text { 
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/total-number-antd-4-19-5-forked-f7spl7?file=/index.css)

Comment: Hey @apostolos. 
<span style={{ right: 0, position: "absolute" }}>
        Showing {range[0]}-{range[1]} of {total}
 </span>
This works for me as well. Just mentioning it so that you don't need to override the base class.